# How can I change the team names in Modern Warfare 3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

On one server, I noticed that it had changed the team names from "Spetsnaz" and "PMC" to "Russians" and "Americans". How can I do something similar?

Comment: Just a downvote. Atleast post some comment or reply.

Comment: Generally questions asking for mod recommendations are off-topic here, but questions that ask how to do something (where an answer might be a mod or it might not) are okay. I revised your question to remove the mod request.

Answer (score -1):

On a map like Village it is PMC and the Milita. There is Delta and Spetnaz, but there is no Russians and American teams.  That can only happen if there is a hacker in the lobby.

Answer (score -2):

It depends what on the map and where it is located. For example in a Russain map it will be Russians and American but in a map like Village it would be PMC and Spetnaz because it is in a Spetnaz map.

Comment: I haven't played MW3 for a while, but I'm quite sure there's no American/Russian team setup on any map, without modding the server. Russians are always Spetsnaz, and so on.